# Usage of "p." vs "pp." to denote two separate pages

Tags: abbreviations, citation, reference

I understand that "p." is used for single page references, and "pp." for multipage pages. However, if I'm quoting something from p. 35 and p. 40 from the same book, should I use "p. 35 and p. 40", or "pp. 35 and 40"?

Comment: A matter of personal choice/style.

Comment: Would you say 'pages 35 and 40' or 'page 35 and 40'?

Answer (score 1):

While this issue may be covered in style guides, I would suggest, absent any clear convention to which to defer, that the choice might be situational.

If you are referencing separate items, though both may directly support your particular content, that have no strong relation to each other more so than expected by appearing in nearby pages, then you might choose the first option, to emphasize the distinctness of the references.

Alternatively, if the two pages include a continuation of the same reference, such as consecutively-numbered diagrams that are placed on non-consecutive pages for typographic considerations, then you might choose the second option, to emphasize the continuity of the sequence.